# Script with ttk theme doesn't open in VSC

Tags: tkinter, tcl, ttk

I'm trying out Azure theme from https://github.com/rdbende/Azure-ttk-theme. When i just double click example file(Azure-ttk-theme-main\azure dark\example.py) it works perfectly, but if I open the script in VSC and try to run it i get an error:
root.tk.call('source', 'azure dark.tcl')
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't read file "azure dark.tcl": no such file or directory

What is the problem?

Comment: Probably not running the python script in the right working directory.

Comment: Have you set up VSC to run python scripts?  Is the python  path in VSC different from that when you double click?

Comment: Is this a checkout from before or after https://github.com/rdbende/Azure-ttk-theme/pull/18 was merged? That would appear to fix the sort of problem you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your code. You do:

```py
root.tk.call('source', 'azure dark.tcl')
```

but the [documentation](https://github.com/rdbende/Azure-ttk-theme/blob/main/README.md) says to do:

```py
root.tk.call("source", "azure.tcl")
root.tk.call("set_theme", "dark")
```

Looking at the source of the theme, all the other things involved (all subsidiary scripts and resources) are designed to be relative to the location of the `azure.tcl` script. That main script (which includes some critical pieces) can be loaded with any path… so long as it is actually there (along with all the other pieces).

But you were just giving a wrong path to only part of the theme.

Comment: The code's a nearly perfect Tcl package, except for lacking a `pkgIndex.tcl` (and not being namespaced, a not-too-terrible sin for this sort of task).